# Can I get npm / gyp to use ccache?

Tags: npm, gyp, ccache

[`ccache`](http://ccache.samba.org/) is a fantastic way to speed up building C binaries which you have already built previously, by caching the results.  (Another great tool is `distcc`, which will pass code to other machines for parallel compilation!)

**Can I get `npm` to use `ccache` when it build C files using `gyp`?**

Here is a way to test:

```
$ time npm install mmmagic
...
npm install mmmagic  103.83s user 9.06s system 100% cpu 1:51.84 total

$ rm -rf node_modules/mmmagic

$ time npm install mmmagic
...
npm install mmmagic  103.48s user 8.59s system 102% cpu 1:48.87 total
```

If we can use `ccache`, it should be significantly faster on the second attempt.

Another way to see if `ccache` is being called, and if it is helping, is to run this in a separate terminal while a build is underway:

```
$ watch -d ccache -s
```

This will display a live update of `ccache`'s statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting your environment variables correctly.
For a C compiler: `export CC="ccache gcc"` (or `export CC="ccache clang"`) should work fine.

Comment: I am also going to **`export CXX="ccache g++"`** in case that is needed for a package in future.

Comment: FWIW, here is the final time: `npm install mmmagic  6.56s user 3.14s system 93% cpu 10.377 total` :)

Comment: Nice :-) Glad to have helped!